# StartScan() doesn't work

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

I want to make some scan of the Access Points, but the method `wifiManager.startScan()` doesn't work in my code :

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonMeasure:

       wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true); //Edit
       timer2 = new Timer(WifiActivity.this);

       while(broadcastReceiver.getMeasureFinished()<=49){
           Log.d("info7","mesure" + broadcastReceiver.getMeasureFinished());
           success = false;
            while(success==false){
            success=wifiManager.startScan();
                Log.d("info2","startScan : " + success);
            }
       }


        case R.id.buttonLocate:
            //localization.
        }
   }
```

Eclipse is well enter in the loop, but doesn't want to read `wifiManager.startScan();`, what is the cause? Thanks!

Comment: Did you put the permission on Manifest ( android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE )?
Did you use setWifiEnabled(true) to turn on wifi?

Comment: Yes I put the permission on Manifest. I add in the code `setWifiEnabled(true)` (cf. Edit) but the problem stays.